# Ansible: check prompt value

Tags: ansible, prompt

I created an Ansible playbook script, to run it have need user interaction.
Now I need to check if the user insert correctly the value when I prompt it.

```
  vars_prompt:
  - name: "vm_env"
    prompt: "vm_env (values: PRD, TST, DEV)"
    default: "DEV"
    private: false
```

How can I check if the user insert correctly only one of these values (PRD, TST, DEV), and in case stop script?

Thanks for the support
Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an Ansible [assert module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/assert_module.html) to validate things and fail with appropriate error message if condition is not matched.

Example:

```yaml
  vars_prompt:
  - name: "vm_env"
    prompt: "vm_env (values: PRD, TST, DEV)"
    default: "DEV"
    private: false

  tasks:
  # "|lower" filter used to fix any case inconsistency, not required if case should match
  - assert:
      that:
      - vm_env|lower in [ 'prd', 'tst', 'dev' ]
      fail_msg: "VM environment should be one of: PRD, TST, DEV"
```

Comment: In the prompt, is it possible to disable <enter> without value, or force to use a value between accepted?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to prevent empty <enter> being pressed. But the `default` parameter should take care of it.

Comment: Hi seshadri_c, I found the solution: until: vm_ip_result.user_input|length > 0

Answer (score 1):

Use [pause](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pause_module.html#ansible-builtin-pause-pause-playbook-execution) if you want to give a user the chance to improve. However, there is no *default*.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - pause:
        prompt: "vm_env (values: PRD, TST, DEV)"
      register: result
      until: result.user_input|default('') in ['PRD', 'TST', 'DEV']
      retries: 3
      delay: 0
    - set_fact:
        vm_env: "{{ result.user_input }}"
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] ****

TASK [pause] ****
[pause]
vm_env (values: PRD, TST, DEV):
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ****
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => {
    "vm_env": "PRD"
}

PLAY RECAP ****
localhost: ok=3 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
```

---

**Notes**

1. Be aware though that if you use the above with 'yes' or 'no' in the values, that the set_fact after will turn the user_input info a boolean ('true'/ 'false')! (credit @Monger39)

```yaml
    - pause:
        prompt: "vm_env (values: yes, no)"
      register: result
    - debug:
        msg: |-
          result.user_input: {{ result.user_input }}
          result.user_input|type_debug: {{ result.user_input|type_debug }}
    - set_fact:
        vm_env: "{{ result.user_input }}"
    - debug:
        msg: |-
          vm_env: {{ vm_env }}
          vm_env|type_debug: {{ vm_env|type_debug }}
```

gives the output below for 'yes'

```yaml
TASK [pause] ********************************************************
[pause]
vm_env (values: yes, no):
yes^Mok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    result.user_input: yes
    result.user_input|type_debug: AnsibleUnsafeText

TASK [set_fact] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    vm_env: True
    vm_env|type_debug: bool
```

and similar output for 'no'

```yaml
TASK [pause] ********************************************************
[pause]
vm_env (values: yes, no):
no^Mok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    result.user_input: no
    result.user_input|type_debug: AnsibleUnsafeText

TASK [set_fact] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    vm_env: False
    vm_env|type_debug: bool
```

2. Despite the implicit convesion of yes/no to True/False it's possible to test the strings in the *until* loop. The tasks below work as expected

```yaml
    - pause:
        prompt: "vm_env (values: yes, no)"
      register: result
      until: result.user_input|default('') in ['yes', 'no']
      retries: 3
      delay: 0
    - debug:
        msg: "User entered: {{ result.user_input|bool|ternary('yes', 'no') }}"
```

See:

- [Testing truthiness](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-truthiness)
- [Example 272. truthy, falsy](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vbotka/ansible-examples/master/examples/example-272/test-001.yml)

Comment: Thank you for your support. I tried to use your code, but I receive an error always, not accept any values, I tried to insert PRD or prd but it didn't accept.

Comment: You're welcome. I double-checked the code again. It's working for me. I've added an example of the output.

Comment: be aware though that if you use the above with 'yes' or 'no' in the values, that the set_fact after will turn the user_input info a boolean ('true'/ 'false') !

Comment: @Monger39, Thank you! I added notes on this.